# Need to convert UTC date time into local timezone in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datetime, timezone

We are currently doing an upgrade on Oracle source, because of which all the date time field timezone will change to UTC.

Currently, we have SSIS packages in place for moving data from Oracle to SQL Server Database.

Is there any way we could have a shortcut to change the dates to local timzezone before moving them in our database in SQL Server? Rather than updating each Package/Procedure to include the timezone change. If its a date field coming up, change the timezone from UTC to local time before adding it to the Database in SQL Server.

Comment: What is the data type of the columns in Oracle and in SQL Server?  Oracle doesn't have a `datetime`.  Are you using `date`, `timestamp`, `timestamp with time zone`, or `timestamp with local time zone` in Oracle?  What data type are you using in SQL Server?

Comment: In both SQL Server and Oracle we are using Date. This convesion is happening from the backend so by default all the times would be in UTC. The data type for the date fields wont change. I am looking for something to trigger on any date insert to change the timezone to local from UTC. So I dont have to change each and every package.

Comment: A SQL Server `date` does not have a time component.  So other than cases where the Oracle `date` time zone conversion changes the day rather than just the time, you wouldn't care about the time zone.  What "local time zone" are you converting to?  The time zone of the server?  Of the client session?  Something else?  Are you only concerned with `insert` operations rather than changing the existing data?  Where are the dates coming from (i.e. are your `insert` operations using `sysdate` or `systimestamp` for their date values?).

Comment: Just the inserts at the moment. The existing data isnt changing in the SQL Server. We are converting to AEST. The server timezone is in AEST. We do not want to display dates/times in UTC. Sorry We are using SQL Server Datetime data type so we are having both dates and times.

Comment: OK.  And where are the dates coming from?  Are you using `sysdate` or `systimestamp` in your `insert` statements?  Or Are you getting a UTC date from somewhere else?

Comment: They are coming from Oracle Server in UTC time zone and I have to convert it to AEST time zone in SQL Server database